# Different storyboards for iPhone and iPad in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, storyboard

I am using different storyboards for iPhone and iPad. **Main.storyboard** and **Main~iPad.storyboard**. But when I try to set assets in the storyboard it shows them in iPhone sizes due to which I am having issues setting those assets in the correct place.

Is there a way to make it detect the correct assets as per storyboard? such that it shows iPhone assets for **Main.storyboard** and iPad assets for **Main~ipad.storyboard**?

Comment: Make 1 storyboard for both iPhone and iPad using Adaptive Layout. Xcode 6 has this facility.

Comment: UI is quite different for iPhone and iPad. So, I cant manage them both using the same storyboard

Comment: Why you having issue setting in the correct place? It there something wrong?

Comment: Yes. The problem is it shows the size of iPhone while setting and when it runs it fits the iPad image in that side which gets cut off or distorted.

Comment: @SahilTyagi : Hope this helps : http://www.smikeapps.com/working-with-multiple-storyboards/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the Devices to "Universal":

[image]