# How to call different Storyboards in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am using two storyboard first one for iphone `Main.storyboard` and second one is `Main_iPad.storyboard` and i wants to call separately for iPad and iPhone i am using this code:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)  {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
    EABaseRootVC *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"root2"];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
    self.window.rootViewController=navController;
}
else
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    EABaseRootVC *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"root"];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
    self.window.rootViewController=navController;
}
```

But its always shows iPhone assets for Main.storyboard.

i am already follow this [Different storyboards for iPhone and iPad in xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813647/different-storyboards-for-iphone-and-ipad-in-xcode-6)

if you have any other idea so please suggest me.
what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To identify Apple devices specifically whether it is `iPhone` or `iPad` use below code:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    // code for iPad
}else{
    // code for iPhone
}
```

And must add these two keys inside your project's `.plist` file.

```
Main storyboard file base name (iPad)
Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)
```

See image:

[image]

Comment: I have already added these things in my info.plist file but not working.

Comment: probably you have updated another plist file in your project just double check it ..this code works fine

Comment: yes i know that this code work fine but not at my end ok let me check.

Comment: You need to make sure that your project is configured to build a "Universal" app not only iPhone.