# Add two Storyboards to project for different languages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, multilingual

I want to add a right to left language to my project. May I have two Storyboard one of them for LTR and another for RTL languages? How?

Comment: you can use two storyboard for iPad and iPhone separately [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39594671/4003548) my ans but i think its not possible(not sure) to use two diff storyboard for iphone, you can go with localization.

Comment: https://ayeohyes.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/localizing-storyboards-and-xibs/

Comment: Many of the LTR and RTL issues can be addressed by using leading & trailing constraints. These will "flip" when the app is run in a RTL locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use two storyboards to do it. You can put an if statement in your appDelegate class to check if the device language is RTL or LTR, then switch between storyboards by their ID.

```
let preferredLang = NSLocale.preferredLanguages().first!
    if NSLocale.characterDirectionForLanguage(preferredLang) == .RightToLeft {
        storyboard = "Main"
    }else{
        storyboard = "MainEn"
    }
let Main = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcMain");
    self.window?.rootViewController=Main
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change direction of your components in code programmatically too.

Comment: But how?, A code snippet in your answer would be appreciated.